# Pivot array based on row count

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

I need to "pivot" it to get :

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 2 [3] => 5 [4] => 3 [5] => 6 )
```

by "pivot" I mean, let's imagine that the array is stored a 2 x 3 matrix (2 rows, and 3 columns). My goal is to pivot it, so that the matrix is now a 3 x 2 matrix (3 rows, 2 columns)

for that of course I need an extra argument, let's say "number of rows" (in this case this is like 2 rows)

I did the following:

```
function pivotArray($array, $nbrRows)
{
  $countTotal = count($array);
  $countCols = $countTotal / $nbrRows;

  $chunk = array_chunk($array,$countCols);

  $out = array();
  for ($row=0;$row<$nbrRows;$row++) {
    for ($col=0;$col<$countCols;$col++) {
    $out[$col][$row] = $chunk[$row][$col];
    }
  }

  $arraySingle = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $out);

  return $arraySingle;    
}
```

it works as designed but I wonder whether there is a better way to do that ? for instance avoiding the 2 for loops ? and also avoid the array_merge ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pivot"? It's not clear what your algorithm is for getting from input to output.

Comment: let us know what @Nick  said.

Comment: sorry that was not clear indeed. I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reporcessing the array a few times, this code builds an intermediate array and spreads the elements based on `$position % $countCols`.  I've also introduced `ceil()` to the count of columns in case there is an odd number of elements...

```
function pivotArray($array, $nbrRows)
{
    $countTotal = count($array);
    $countCols = ceil($countTotal / $nbrRows);
    $arraySingle = [];
    foreach ( $array as $position => $value )   {
        $arraySingle[$position % $countCols][] = $value;
    }

    return array_merge(...$arraySingle);
}
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/iWYvC  (make sure to tell him version supported `...`)

Comment: thanks a lot! in this very case (see my edit) $countTotal is necessarily even (n x m "matrix"). As for the version, 5.6.39 so all good.